# Angularjs TypeError: <serviceName>.<functionName> is not a function at Scope.$scope.<functionName>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I defined a service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('vAppName.services')
   .factory('UpdateWarehouse', function($resource, configSettings) {
     var updateWarehouse = $resource(configSettings.apiServiceUrl + 'api/v1/updateWarehouse', {
       'update': {
         method: 'POST'
       }
     });
     return updateWarehouse;
   });
```

In the controller, list the service in the controller:

```
angular.module('vAppName.controllers')
    .controller('VCtrlName', [<list of other properties>'UpdateWarehouse',
        function(<list of other properties>, updateWarehouse) { 
        ...bunch of functions and properties

            $scope.updateWrh = function() {
                updateWarehouse.update({

                    startDate: $scope.updateWrhParams.startDate,
                    endDate: $scope.updateWrhParams.endDate

                }).$promise.then(function(){
                     $scope.messageModalVariables = {
            messageTitle: 'Warehouse Update Complete',
            messageDisplay: 'Warehouse has been updated.',
            messageType: 'Success',
            okIsHidden: false,
            yesNoIsHidden: true
          };
                    $scope.openMessageModal($scope.messageModalVariables);

                }, function (error) {
                     $scope.messageModalVariables = {
            messageTitle: 'Error Warehouse Update',
            messageDisplay: error.data,
            messageType: 'Error',
            okIsHidden: false,
            yesNoIsHidden: true
          };
          $scope.openMessageModal($scope.messageModalVariables);
                });
            };

        } //end main function
    ]);
```

This is the HTML

```
<div style="margin: 5%; display: inline-block;">
                                <label id="startDateLabel" style="margin-left: 5%">Start Date:</label>
                                <date-picker id="startDatePicker" type="text" model="updateWrhParams.startDate" style="width: 50%; float: right;"></date-picker>
                            </div>
                            <div style="margin: 5%; display: inline-block;">
                                <label id="endDateLabel" style="margin-left: 5%">End Date:</label>
                                <date-picker id="endDatePicker" type="text" model="updateWrhParams.endDate" style="width: 50%; float: right;"></date-picker>
                            </div>
<button type="button" id="updateBtnWrh" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 3%; background-color: #41a334;" ng-disabled="isAdmin == true" ng-click="updateWrh()">Update</button>
```

When I click the `Update' button, the function`updateWrh()`is called but the`update' function in the service is not recognized as function.

Why is my service not recognized as a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined the [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) properly. Second argument is for *paramDefaults* not *actions*

```
 var updateWarehouse = $resource(URL, {}, {
   'update': {
     method: 'POST'
   }
 });
```

instead of

```
 var updateWarehouse = $resource(URL, {
   'update': {
     method: 'POST'
   }
 });
```

Comment: Damn...that was it!  I copied the format of the resource using another application.  It did not have parameters and did not have empty brackets but defined the function this way: `.factory(UpgradeDB`, function($rootScope, $resource, CONFIG) { var upgradeDB = $resoruce(CONFIG.apiServiceUrl + 'api/upgradedb', {'save': {method: 'POST'}}); return updateDB;});` Is adding the parameter $rootScope not  make it necessary to have empty brackets as parameters?

Comment: @GloriaSantin, $rootScope doesn't make any difference, Why version of angular is being used in other app?

Comment: In the application that I am adding the resource uses v1.4.12 while the version that had the resource `UpdateDB` that I used as a template uses v1.2.23